How to validate mathematical signals in php
I'm having problems where the user can set in my cash flow system some formulas. The problem is that he is able to put some mathematical mistakes such as +1[SELL]+5. The SELL is a variable that breaks because the lack of mathematical signals after the +1.
I have tried a regex like '/\d+(?![\/*\-+])/' to fix that, but the code "complains" that the 5 doesn't have a sign after.
I expected that the pattern skips the validation if the number is at the end of the string.

It should be '/\d+(?![\d\/*+-])/', but if you want to avoid matching a number at the end of string, use a positive lookahead with a negated character class, \d+(?=[^\/*\-+]).See https://regex101.com/r/ySFXDd/1

What are mathematical signals? Do you mean math symbols?

Yes like: (+ - * / )

Kind off, the first one you give as example dont work int the regex site you send me '/\d+(?![\d/*+-])/', but the second one does, if i dont put a big number like +1[SELL]+555. The regex will point out that 55 is incorrect

You can use
\b\d+\b(?=[^\/*+-])

See the regex demo.
Details:

\b\d+\b - one or two digits not enclosed with word chars
(?=[^\/*+-]) - a positive lookahead that requires the next char after the digit sequence matched with \d+ to be any char but a /, *, + and - chars.


Thank you soo muchn you have solved my problem
